# how to pass default event argument and an argument in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the function I want to invoke in an input type:

```
_handleOnEnterPress = (e, receiverUserId) => {
     if (e.keyCode === 13) { // guess keycode 13 is enter?
       console.log("pressed enter. user id = ",receiverUserId)
     }
  };
```

and this is the input type I want to invoke when ENTER is pressed, I used onKeydown

```
<input className="popup-input" 
  onKeyDown={this._handleOnEnterPress(chatFriendPopPup.id)} 
  onChange={this._handleMessageTextChange} 
  type='text'
/>
```

when I press enter, it's not logging on the console. I used e(event) default arg so it can detect the keycode 13 (enter) but I guess the if fails? since the receiverUserId is on 2nd index, do I not have to pass e (event) arg on onKeyDown when the function is invoked?

Comment: use `.bind(chatFriendPopPup.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `onKeyDown={(e) => this._handleOnEnterPress(e, chatFriendPopPup.id)}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an arrow function to catch the event and then pass that event object as well **any argument** you like to the handler method of your choosing.

```
handler(e, someInput) {
    // do something in here

    if (someInput === 'foo') console.log('bar');
}

render() {
    const someArg = 'foo';
    return (
        <button onClick={e => this.handler(e, someArg)}>Do something</button>
    )
}
```